# How to display checked radio button based on previous value?

Tags: java, forms, jsp, jdbc

I have a form which gets user information and saves it into database. My form consists of text fields and radio buttons.
(I am using jsp, bean  servlet, jdbc)

Now i have made another form which is to edit the user entered information, it also shows their previous entered information in the text fields.

I can display the previous entered information in the text fields but my problem is that I cannot show the previous checked radio buttons, how can i do that?

Below is an example of text field showing previous entered value

```
<tr>
    <td>Email:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="editregisterEmail" maxlength="10" size="15" value="<jsp:getProperty name="StudentBean" property="email"/>"></td>
</tr>
```

The problem is here, how can I show users the previous checked radio button for them to recheck?

I have the following code which gets previous radio button value which was checked by user

```
<jsp:getProperty name="StudentBean" property="department"/>
```

Below is the problem

```
<tr>
    <td>Department: </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="editregisterDepartment" value="Information Technology"> Information Technology  
        <input type="radio" name="editregisterDepartment" value="Business Administration"> Business Administration
        <input type="radio" name="editregisterDepartment" value="Engineering"> Engineering
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you better use expression language (EL) as below:

```
<tr>
    <td>Department: </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="editregisterDepartment" value="Information Technology" ${requestScope['StudentBean'].department == 'Information Technology'? 'checked':''}> Information Technology  
        <input type="radio" name="editregisterDepartment" value="Business Administration" ${requestScope['StudentBean'].department == 'Business Administration'? 'checked':''}> Business Administration
        <input type="radio" name="editregisterDepartment" value="Engineering" ${requestScope['StudentBean'].department == 'Engineering'? 'checked':''}> Engineering
    </td>
</tr>
```

requestScope can be change depending in which scope you have defined your bean

Answer (score 0):

A simple switch will do.

```
<%
    StudentBean s=new StudentBean();
    switch(s.getDepartment()){
        case "Information Technology":
%>
            <input type="radio" name="editregisterDepartment" value="Information Technology" checked> Information Technology  
            <input type="radio" name="editregisterDepartment" value="Business Administration"> Business Administration
            <input type="radio" name="editregisterDepartment" value="Engineering"> Engineering
<%
            break;
        case "Business Administration":
%>
            <input type="radio" name="editregisterDepartment" value="Information Technology"> Information Technology  
            <input type="radio" name="editregisterDepartment" value="Business Administration" checked> Business Administration
            <input type="radio" name="editregisterDepartment" value="Engineering"> Engineering
<%
            break;
        case "Engineering":
%>
            <input type="radio" name="editregisterDepartment" value="Information Technology"> Information Technology  
            <input type="radio" name="editregisterDepartment" value="Business Administration"> Business Administration
            <input type="radio" name="editregisterDepartment" value="Engineering" checked> Engineering
<%
            break;
   }
%>
```

If you are not using JavaEE 7, you will not be able to switch on a string value, then you will have to use `if`s, like this:

```
<%
    StudentBean s=new StudentBean();
    if(s.getDepartment().equals("Information Technology"){
%>
            <input type="radio" name="editregisterDepartment" value="Information Technology" checked> Information Technology  
            <input type="radio" name="editregisterDepartment" value="Business Administration"> Business Administration
            <input type="radio" name="editregisterDepartment" value="Engineering"> Engineering
<%
    }else if(s.getDepartment().equals("Business Administration"){
%>
            <input type="radio" name="editregisterDepartment" value="Information Technology"> Information Technology  
            <input type="radio" name="editregisterDepartment" value="Business Administration" checked> Business Administration
            <input type="radio" name="editregisterDepartment" value="Engineering"> Engineering
<%
    }else if(s.getDepartment().equals("Engineering"){
%>
            <input type="radio" name="editregisterDepartment" value="Information Technology"> Information Technology  
            <input type="radio" name="editregisterDepartment" value="Business Administration"> Business Administration
            <input type="radio" name="editregisterDepartment" value="Engineering" checked> Engineering
<%
   }
%>
```

Comment: I don't think so. But if you can test, that would be perfect. Also updated my answer so you can see how it's done with `if`s ;)

Comment: I have tried both methods, however im getting the following error in the if ( code ) part, " non-static method getDepartment() cannot be referenced from static context "

Comment: Use the lower case variable name in jsp:getProperty name="studentBean" and then in ifs. It is not recommended to name your variables with upper case. In this example it clashes with class name.

Comment: @user3829075 Sorry, i thought that you made your bean with static methods, you will have to create a object based on your class. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the if condition. It worked for me in my jsp page. I am using java 8 and apache tomcat 6.

```
<%
String id=request.getParameter("id");
User u=UserDao.getRecordById(Integer.parseInt(id));
%>
...
...


<tr><td>Sex:</td>
<td>
<%if(u.getSex().equalsIgnoreCase("male")) { %>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked/>Male 
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"/>Female 
<% } else if(u.getSex().equalsIgnoreCase("female")) {%>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" />Male 
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" checked/>Female 
<% } %>
</td></tr>
```